# Mix OAuth ("Individual Accounts") and Azure Active Directory ("Organizational Accounts") authentication in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to add an admin section / folder / area (whichever works) to an MVC5 website that is protected by Azure Active Directory.

At creation of the website, the option to use "Individual Accounts" was selected, and I have a working implementation that allows a user to register an account and login to the website (via **ASPNet Identity**) - this is working well.

Current Use Cases:

- Any user can browse to the root of the website (e.g. `http://example.com`), and see certain resources;
- When the user logs in with their account, they can access protected resources (e.g. `http://example.com/account`) that are specific to their account;

New Use Case:

- User navigates to `http://example.com/admin`
- User is promoted to authenticate against Azure Active Directory
- User can now browse `http://example.com/admin`

The idea being that any staff member in the organization can access the admin section of the website to perform admin functions.

I've found and read a lot of information about doing EITHER "Individual Account" or "Organizational Account" authentication, but nothing on how to go about mixing these together.

Is this possible?

Comment: We are in a similar situation now, and could not figure out a solution. What we did at the end was to create two separate sites for individual account and organizational account.

Comment: I think the solution is to configure the Azure Active Directory auth as per the existing samples, and setup the web.config security section to allow access to all areas of the site except for the given folder.  I haven't had time to check this out yet but intend to do so soon.